# Big size file download

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

On my web page I have the following JS code to download file from server on user click:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", otherUrl, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], 
                        {type: oReq.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')});
    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadLink.href = objectURL;
    downloadLink.click();
};
oReq.onprogress = function(oEvent) {
    var percentage = Math.round(oEvent.loaded/oEvent.total*100);
    
    downloadProgressDiv.innerHTML = "Progress: " + percentage + " % (" + oEvent.loaded 
                                    + " from " + oEvent.total + " )";
};
oReq.send(this.path);
```

It works for files below 1GB size. The issue I came across happens when file size I'm trying to download is about 3GB. In this case `onprogress` method works as with other files, `onload` method is invoked once download is completed, but `oReq.response=null`. Also I'm able to save the file, but its size is 1KB.

Could you, please, give me any tips why does this happens? Any alternative ways of doing this?

Comment: Probably because the browser runs out of memory, when you ask it to create an object URL for an object of such size ...

Comment: _"Any alternative ways of doing this?"_ - ditch the AJAX, and submit a form with `method="post"` to send whatever parameters you need for this ...?

Comment: Good old-fashioned form submission. Did this way and it works with 3GB file. Add this to the answer below, I would vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any tips why does this happens?

Probably because the browser runs out of memory, when you ask it to create an object URL for an object of such size.

> Any alternative ways of doing this?

Don't use AJAX, but instead submit a form with `method="post"` to send whatever parameters you need for this.